# Samba performance tuning

Tags: samba, io

I'm using Samba to share a folder from Linux to a Windows client (Windows Server 2012 R2). The disk backing the Linux share is pretty fast (NAS of 500+ MB/s). However, when I benchmark the IO performance from Windows machine, I can only get around 200 MB/s.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Set these options (improve from 100 MB/s to 200 MB/s)

   ```
   aio read size = 1
   aio write size = 1
   aio write behind = true
   ```
2. Set these options (no improvement)

   ```
   socket options=SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072 TCP_NODELAY
   ```

What can I do do to improve the IO performance?

Comment: What kind of network connection do you have between the machines?  And what tests/benchmarks do you run to get 500 MB/sec to the NAS?

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewHenle I have 10 GbE network. And both dd, fio, iozone was used to benchmark the NAS.

Comment: You have a lot of variables in your setup.  How do you access the NAS disks?  NFS?  And how are you benchmarking from the WIndows SMB client(s)?  There's going to be some performance hit as you're adding the latency of another network hop along with the overhead of Samba, and that performance hit is going to be highly dependent on the specifics of your configuration and the IO pattern you're benchmarking.  And [this link](http://www.arm-blog.com/samba-finetuning-for-better-transfer-speeds/) says to set aio read/write size to 2048.